# error: cannot find symbol class MapSettings - Here Maps Android SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I am following these instructions to write a simple app with Here Maps Android SDK. 
[Create a Simple App using the here android sdk](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html)

Where should this below method get the MapSettings from? I do not see this class in the attached library? HERE_Android_SDK_Starter_v3.7_9

```
private void initialize() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);

    // Set up disk cache path for the map service for this application
    boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
            "{YOUR_CACHE_LOCATION}", "{YOUR_INTENT_NAME}");

    if (!success) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set isolated disk cache path.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    } else {
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                            Map.Animation.NONE);
                    // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you refer to the documentation of the Premium SDK with offline and map loader capabilities, while you try to use the Starter SDK that doesn't have that feature.

Comment: @Marco Where's the documentation for the Starter SDK then? I have the same problem as OP.

Comment: Starter SDK docus for Android can be found here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-starter/dev_guide/topics/maps.html

Answer (score 0):

HERE SDK for Android, version 4.1.5.0 (Lite Edition) and premium addition enables you to build powerful map applications. please use https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html for new documentation reference.